# What is the default value for CSP HTTP Header "frame-ancestors", if no arguments are provided?

Tags: html, web, iframe, cross-browser, content-security-policy

What is the default value for CSP frame-ancestors, if no arguments are provided?

There is a ton of online material pertaining to how to set this CSP to specific value. But I can't find any material talks about what the default value is, if no options are provided.

For example, if the HTTP Response Header simply states:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors
```

[image]

Comment: Per the CSP spec, if the frame-ancestors directive is present but has no value, the required browser behavior is that the browser must disallow the document from being framed by any ancestors.  The specific requirements are at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#frame-ancestors-navigation-response and https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#match-url-to-source-list

Comment: To summarize the spec requirements: https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#match-url-to-source-list has an algorithm to check if the URL of a source trying to frame the document matches the value of the document’s frame-ancestors directive; but if the frame-ancestors value is empty, then what the spec calls the “source list” for the directive is empty and so always hits step 2 of that algorithm, which is *If source list is an empty list, return "Does Not Match"*, and so the calling algorithm at https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-csp/#frame-ancestors-navigation-response returns "Blocked"

Comment: @sideshowbarker Make that an answer!